# How do define a constant value from user input after class construction

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

As part of personal Arduino project, I have added an initial "input" stage that asks the user to enter an integer representing the number of vials in their carousel (that particular info is not relevant to the issue, I just thought I'd better mention it.) This input is received via LCD button keypad.

This integer will be used solely in a custom class called Vial_Control.

Currently, if I'm using a 16-vial system, I hard code the "16" and use the '#define' directive throughout ('const int' would also work, but not solve the problem.)

The catch is that when I ask for user input, I have already created my global variables in my main file that represent the class constructor object for Vial_Control.

```
#ifndef Vial_Control_h
#define Vial_Control_h
#include "Arduino.h"

class Vial_Control
{
    public:
        Vial_Control();   // constructor
        void setSystemVialCount(int vialCount);
        // bunch of other unrelated functions
    private:
        #define VIAL_COUNT 16         // I used to use this
        static const int VIAL_COUNT;  // now I use this
        // bunch of other...

};

#endif
```

now in my implementation file

```
Vial_Control::Vial_Control()
{
    // I used to assign 'static const int VIAL_COUNT' here
    // but turned away from that.

    // bunch of other...
}

void Vial_Control::setSystemVialCount(int vialCount)
{
    /* I started to do this, even prior to defining the variable
     * as 'static'.  I added 'static' as per suggestion from the
     * compiler, although I'm not entirely convinced that this is
     * the best solution. */
    VIAL_COUNT = vialCount;
}
```

So, in my ArdProj.c file, the Vial_Control constructor is made, then in the initial stage portion (Arduino calls this `setup()`) I ask for user input, then call the function `setSystemVialCount(int vialCount)`, passing in the input.

Is this the best solution for what I'm after?  Will the `static const int VIAL_COUNT` hold the value "16" for the entirety of runtime?

I received errors when I did not add the `static`, from what I've read, due to to the variable not being initialized upon construction.

If anything is unclear, let me know, I'll add more.

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: Using `#define VIAL_COUNT 16` means all occurrences of `VIAL_COUNT` will be substituted by 16. You essentially wrote `static const int 16;`.

Comment: You could in your implementation file `Vial_Control::VIAL_COUNT = 16`

Comment: You cannot change a `const` after it's been initialized. That's what makes it `const`. And I don't think you can portably get user input during static initialization. Either make your constant non-static and use user input to initialize it at a later time, or don't make it `const`. Maybe you could use a local static constant, which is only initialized when it's first encountered.

Comment: If you think you need a macro in C++, 99.99% of the time, you thought wrong.

Comment: @JakeFreeman - that doesn't solve the variability issue of an 8, 10 or 20-vial system.  Thanks though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I wanted to do that originally.  Non-static and initialize after construction.  Maybe I'm writing it wrong, but I have `const int VIAL_CONTROL` as a private variable, not initialized.  Then, `Vial_Control` constructor is made, then I use that function to initialize `VIAL_CONTROL` variable with the input variable from the user. However, it is written as an assignment. Thus I receive the following error: "In constructor 'Vial_Control::Vial_Control()`, uninitialized member VIAL_COUNT with `const` type `const int`."  Then, the function produces an error regarding assignment.

Comment: @underscore_d - I wish I knew enough to agree with you, but I'll come to that road eventually.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem.

Is there any means by which you can obtain information from the hardware (the vial carousel) by which the device can tell you if it is a 16 vial system? If so, then you could use that in your ctor and VIAL_COUNT could be set there. Example:

```
Vial_Control::Vial_Control(int nVials=16): vialCount(nVials)
{
}
```

In this manner const members can be initialized at creation with their initial values. As I understand what you're doing, the user input is giving you the number of vials in use, and the member const int vialCount is the maximum number of vials available on the machine. (?)

Comment: It's may be unclear exactly what you are suggesting. You should provide the modified header to better illustrate your proposed solution. The provided code is not compatible with the header in the question.

Comment: That's exactly right, and ironically, it would be better for there to be no input at all from the user!  This carousel unfortunately has no way of communicating that info to the system (even if I tried to make a way that is efficient to the current project and more efficient than the previous project that I'm trying to better-implement.)

Comment: Just to follow up, int nVials as you suggest still has not automated way of obtaining a value upon construction.

Comment: I'm not certain what automated means in this context. It merely allows you to assign the value to your const member variable within the constructor.

Comment: Automated - referencing the suggestion by natersoz about acquiring a vial count from the carousel itself...automated might not have been the best word, more just like a technology that "discovers" the vial count and "feeds" it to the Arduino software to be processed and held during the entire runtime.

Comment: But this is already straying far from my original issue, which, if there is an implementable solution, will be far more efficient than optimizing the carousel.